# Error when trying to collect data from multiple go routines

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to run multiple goroutines in parallel and then collect the results of those calculations once they have all completed.

No matter what I try though, I get the following error:

fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Here is the layout of my code:

```
 func Function(inputs) {

     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     wg.Add(numBatch)

     deltaChan := make(chan DeltaPair)

     for b := 1 ; b <= numBatch ; b++ {

          ... some calculations

          go BackPropagate(otherinputs, deltaChan, &wg)
     }

     for delta := range deltaChan {

           AddNeurons(&nDeltas, &delta.n)
          AddSynapses(&sDeltas, &delta.s)
     }

     wg.Wait()

     close(deltaChan)
}

func BackPropagate(otherinputs, deltaChan chan<- DeltaPair, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

     defer (*wg).Done()

     ... some calculations

     deltaChan <- DeltaPair{nDeltas, sDeltas}
}
```

Comment: A for range loop over a channel exits when the channel closes, but you're closing the channel after the for loop;

Comment: The above-noted range-before-close is indeed the issue. Also, rather than `(*wg).Done()` you should just be calling `wg.Done()`. It will handle dereferencing for you as needed.

Comment: appreciate it! that solved the issue